# Removing words in list - loop malfunction

Tags: python, list

I have written a simple for loop meant to check if all of the words in one list are found in a larger list. It is a practice question found 
[here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-ransom-note/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=dictionaries-hashmaps).

I do not understand why my function does not execute properly - After running it, what is left in the sample list "note2" is ['one','today'], so it seems like the loop is somehow skipping over those words. Why is that?! I do not understand it conceptually.

Thank you for your help on this.

Example lists (two pairs of examples):

```
mag1=['two', 'times', 'three', 'is', 'not', 'four']
note1=['two', 'times', 'two', 'is', 'four']

mag2=['give', 'me', 'one', 'grand', 'today', 'night']
note2=['give','one','grand','today']
```

Function:

```
def checkMagazine(magazine, note):
    #Counter(note1).max
    for word in note:
        if word in magazine:
            magazine.remove(word)
            note.remove(word)
            #print(magazine)
            #print(note)
        #print(note)
    if len(note)>0:
        #ans="No"
        print("No")
    else:
        #ans="Yes"
        print("Yes")
```

Comment: I don't know for *absolute sure* that that's your problem, but it definitely sounds like it is. You can't reliably change the size of a collection (like removing from it) while iterating it. That can cause weird behavior (like elements getting skipped). Change to a list comprehension, or, have a second list that's a copy of the original.

Comment: Actually, arguably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742371/why-does-python-skip-elements-when-i-modify-a-list-while-iterating-over-it) is a better dupe.

Comment: If you do not want to iterate you can use something like this:`final = [word for word in mag1 if word not in note1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In the loop you remove elements from the list and then `word` is looking at the elements of the reduced list.**

Copy the lists in the `for` loop line using `note[:]`:

```
def checkMagazine(magazine, note):
    for word in note[:]:
        if word in magazine:
            magazine.remove(word)
            note.remove(word)

mag2=['give', 'me', 'one', 'grand', 'today', 'night']
note2=['give','one','grand','today']

checkMagazine(mag2, note2)
```

Comment: Yes this is what I said. It does not need to be copied. I have edited it.

Comment: Just saw the duplicate indication. Feel free to close and delete it

Comment: Thank you, makis. A question: what does the addition of the [:] actually do? Why does this make it work?

Comment: read the first sentence of my answer

Comment: to answer also here, `[:]` copies the list.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58718886/313935 removing items from a list inside a loop is always a no-go. You can find out yourself by inspecting the result of the `print` statements you've commented out in your code (i.e. the position of items in the list changes every time an item is removed).

Here's another approach:

```
def checkMagazine(magazine, note):    
    matches=0
    for word in note:
        if word in magazine:
            matches+=1

    if matches==len(note):
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")
```